# Exception('Exception caught in workbook destructor. Explicit close() may be required for workbook.'

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I am getting the exception below while running my Python program in Oracle Linux 6.6.
I am using Python version 2.6.

> Exception('Exception caught in workbook destructor. Explicit close()
>   may be required for workbook.'

My code is:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
import mysql.connector
import smtplib
import math
#from xlrd import open_workbook
import numbers, string
import xlsxwriter
import string
import time
import base64
import subprocess
import os
import sys
import commands
import itertools
#import xlwt
import datetime as dt
import email.mime.application
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import datetime,timedelta, date
from email import Encoders
from tempfile import TemporaryFile
#from xlwt import Workbook, XFStyle, Borders, Pattern, Font
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.audio import MIMEAudio
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email.Utils import formatdate
import datetime
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook
from xlsxwriter import Workbook   

curtme = datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now(), '%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S')
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('/Export/Report_'+curtme+'.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
completed_fmt = workbook.add_format({'bold': True, 'border': 6,'align': 'center','valign': 'vcenter','bg_color': 'yellow','font_size':'12', 'font_name':'Calibri'})
worksheet.set_column(0,9,36)
worksheet.merge_range('A2:C6',None, None)
worksheet.merge_range('A2:C6',None, None)
cellformat = workbook.add_format({'bold': True, 'border': 6,'align': 'center','valign': 'vcenter','font_size':'16', 'font_name':'Calibri'})
cellfmt = workbook.add_format({'bold': False, 'border': 6,'align': 'center','valign': 'vcenter','font_size':'12', 'font_name':'Calibri'})
worksheet.insert_image('A1', 'Image/logo.jpg')
worksheet.merge_range('B1:C6', "Report", cellformat)
    rowx = 6
    for colx, value in enumerate(headings):
            worksheet.write(rowx, colx, value, completed_fmt)
            i=1
            for i, row in enumerate(myresult):
                    for j, col in enumerate(row):
                            worksheet.write(i+7, j, col,cellfmt)
    workbook.close()
db.close()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You will get better results when your questions are clear and concise. Some helpful tips are listed in [this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). For python questions specifically, a relevant stack trace is extremely helpful.  Also, unless your code is having issues with imports, we probably don't need you to include all of them. Finally, especially with python, ensure your code is formatted correctly. Many users will skip poorly formatted questions and help those who put in more effort.

Answer (score 2):

The exception says that the `close()` **may** be required. This is to catch xlsxwriter exceptions where an implicit close isn't sufficient.

Since `close()` is already included in your program that isn't the source of the exception.

The actual error will be above it in the stack trace. Some potential issues:

1. The indentation is wrong.
2. `headings` isn't defined.
3. `myresult` isn't defined.

Answer (score 1):

You have opened the file  '/Export/Report_'+curtme+'.xlsx' while executing the code, hence it could not write to the file as it was already open